# How to plot the name of the states in a cartopy map?

Tags: python, cartopy

I have a shapefile with the information of the names of the states of Perú country, and I want to plot them on the map according to their state.

So i did this code:

```
import cartopy
%matplotlib inline
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.img_tiles as cimgt
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from cartopy.feature import NaturalEarthFeature


reader = shpreader.Reader('C:/my/route/STATES_PERU.shp')
counties = list(reader.geometries())
states = reader.records()
state = next(states)

states_att = lambda state: state.attributes['DEPARTAMEN']
states_names = sorted(reader.records(), key=states_att)

COUNTIES = cfeature.ShapelyFeature(counties, ccrs.PlateCarree())
STATES = cfeature.ShapelyFeature(states_names, ccrs.PlateCarree())

fig = plt.figure('map', figsize=(7,7), dpi=200)
ax = fig.add_axes([0.1, 0.12, 0.80, 0.75], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())

l1 = NaturalEarthFeature(category='cultural', name='admin_0_countries', scale='50m', facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(l1, edgecolor='black', linewidth=0.1)

ax.set_extent([-83.0, -66.0, -19.0, 1.0], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.add_feature(COUNTIES, facecolor='none', edgecolor='black')
ax.add_feature(STATES)
```

When i run this code i got this error:

```
AttributeError: 'FionaRecord' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

The variable `COUNTIES` have Polygon elements and the variable `STATES` have FionaRecord elements.

How can i plot the names of the states in the cartopy map, that are inside the variable `STATES`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably easiest to loop over the records that the `shpreader` returns. That allows you to for example get the coordinates of the centroid of the polygon, and use that to plot the name from the attributes.

Using NE sample data:

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects

# get the data
fn = shpreader.natural_earth(
    resolution='10m', category='cultural', 
    name='admin_1_states_provinces',
)
reader = shpreader.Reader(fn)
states = [x for x in reader.records() if x.attributes["admin"] == "Peru"]
states_geom = cfeature.ShapelyFeature([x.geometry for x in states], ccrs.PlateCarree())

data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

# create the plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(7,7), dpi=130, facecolor="w",
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=data_proj),
)

ax.add_feature(cfeature.BORDERS, color="k", lw=0.1)
ax.set_extent([-83.0, -66.0, -19.0, 1.0], crs=data_proj)

ax.add_feature(states_geom, facecolor="none", edgecolor="k")

# add the names
for state in states:
    
    lon = state.geometry.centroid.x
    lat = state.geometry.centroid.y
    name = state.attributes["name"] 
    
    ax.text(
        lon, lat, name, size=7, transform=data_proj, ha="center", va="center",
        path_effects=[PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=5, foreground="w")]
    )
```

This method probably will cause some overlap between the labels. I'm not sure if there are more advanced label placement algorithms available that work well with Matplotlib.

[image]